# C++: Rules for this return {} initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization, aggregate-initialization, value-initialization

I am trying to understand the rules governing the following initialization:

```
struct A {
  const char* s_ptr;
  std::string str;
};

A Foo() {
  return {};
}

A a = Foo();
```

As per my understanding, `a.s_ptr == nullptr` and `a.str` is "empty" string (using string default constructor).

Here's my understanding of the C++ rules which dictate this result.

`return {};` statement is [copy list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (also mentioned [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list)).

Since A is an aggregate, [this rule applies](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.4):

> (dcl.init.list#3.4) Otherwise, if T is an aggregate, aggregate
> initialization is performed

I am guessing since 3.4 is before 3.5, so it applies first.

For aggregate initialization, [these rules apply](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#5):

> (dcl.init.aggr#5) For a non-union aggregate, each element that is not an explicitly
> initialized element is initialized as follows:
>
> - (5.1) If the element has a default member initializer ([class.mem]), the element is initialized from that initializer.
> - (5.2) Otherwise, if the element is
>   not a reference, the element is copy-initialized from an empty
>   initializer list ([dcl.init.list]).

5.2 is used for both `A::s_ptr` and `A::str` above.

`A::s_ptr` is initialized using [this rule](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.11):

> (dcl.init.list#3.11) Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.

`A::str` is initialized using [this rule](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.5):

> (dcl.init.list#3.5) Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Do you observe anything that would contradict your understanding?

Comment: Sounds correct to make. What makes you doubt it?

Comment: perhaps this will work better as an selfanswered question. You can turn the question into "What rules dictate the result of this code?" and move the rest to an answer. Then others will let you know if your understanding is correct  or add another answer if there is something to add

Comment: If `A` is your own type, you could easily add a default initializer `const char* s_ptr {};`, which turns this into case (5.1) and makes it obvious to everyone that you *want* the member initialized. There is no extra runtime cost in spelling out what the compiler would do anyway.